# jquery Set height of containers dynamically based on content, but then resize smaller again

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, height, onchange

I have a dropdown which populates div content according to a select made by the client.

I currently have a function which looks for the height of the tallest container and applies that height to the other containers so that everything is lined up nicely.

When the client selects another option if the content is shorter the container stays the same height. So it will enlarge after different selects are made but not shrink.

Here is my js (I found this on SO):

```
 $('#accountSubtype').change(function(){
    $('#resultsTable').slideDown();
    $('#importantInfo').fadeIn();
        var $highest = null;
        var $hi = 0;
        $(".table-main-2 .cell").each(function(){
            var h = $(this).height();
            if(h > $hi){
                $hi = h;
                $highest = $(this);
        } 
    //highest now contains the div with the highest so lets highlight it
    $('.table-main-2 .cell').css("height", $hi);
    });
```

Here is some html

```
 <div id="option2">
                        <label>Please select your current information:</label>
                        <div  id="secondOption" class="styled-select clearfix">
                            <select name="accountsubtype" id="accountSubtype">
                                <option value="Option" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

 <div class="table-main-1">
                                <div id="a2" class="table-header">
                                    <p class="lrg-txt">Your Current Rate</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="a3" class="cell cell-top">
                                    <p>Tier</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="b3" class="cell cell-top cell-r">
                                    <p>Rate</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="a4" class="cell">
                                    <p id="tier1"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="b4" class="cell cell-r">
                                    <p id="ratet1"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="a5" class="cell">
                                    <p id="tier2"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="b5" class="cell cell-r">
                                    <p id="ratet2"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="a6" class="cell">
                                    <p id="tier3"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="b6" class="cell cell-r">
                                    <p id="ratet3"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div id="a7" class="cell-full clearfix">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="interest_details"></li>
                                        <li id="when_moves"></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Is there a way to recalculate the height after another select. Not sure if I need a delay or to bind it to another event?

TIA
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so simple it's embarrassing.

All I had to do was reset the heights of the elements to zero at the start of the function.

```
$('#accountSubtype').change(function(){
  $('#resultsTable').slideDown();
  $('#importantInfo').fadeIn();
  $('.table-main-2 .cell p').css('height','0px');
    var $highest = null;
    var $hi = 0;
    $(".table-main-2 .cell").each(function(){
        var h = $(this).height();
        if(h > $hi){
            $hi = h;
            $highest = $(this);
        }
    }); //Close the function
//highest now contains the div with the highest so lets highlight it
$('.table-main-2 .cell').css("height", $hi);
});
```